# Stored routine out parameter stub

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, out

I have a mysql 5.5 stored routine:

```
PROCEDURE get_stuff(IN po_id BIGINT, OUT po_name VARCHAR(32), OUT po_value VARCHAR(32)) ...
```

I want call this procedure from other routine, but I dont need all out parameters of previous routine:

```
PROCEDURE do_work(IN po_id BIGINT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE stuff_value VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL;

    CALL get_stuff(po_id, /* dont need this out param */, stuff_value);
    ...
```

Is there a way to stub out parameter of stored routine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't set optional parameters in MySQL stored procedures. There isn't currently a way to define a default value for a parameter and therefore all parameters need to be passed a value.